# credentials file for running mysql related jobs via script?

Tags: mysql, authentication

Is there a method to point mysql to a credentials file instead of entering account passwords directly in scripts?

Example:

```
mysqldump --opt --credfile /etc/mysql_creds mydatabase > output.sql
```

/etc/mysql_creds

```
username=myuser
password=ToPsEcReT
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better to store the credentials in a config file, and load them as an extra-defaults file:

```
$ mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=mycred.cnf ...
```

The config file is the same format as /etc/my.cnf or ~/.my.cnf

```
$ cat mycred.cnf
[mysqldump]
user = myuser
password = xyzzy
```

MySQL 5.6 also introduces encrypted storage of credentials. You can set up an encrypted file ~/.mylogin.cnf:

```
$ mysql_config_editor set --login-path=dump --host=localhost --user=root --password
Enter password:
```

Then you can dump using that login path

```
$ mysqldump --login-path=dump ...
```

Comment: I didn't know about the 5.6 changes, that is a great feature!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out how to do this:

> mysqldump --opt --user=myuser --password=`cat /etc/secure/mysqlpasswd`
>   mydatabase > output.sql

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [mysql-config-editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html)